# I can't see the admin panel of Voyager is it because I am using Windows?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

So, I have installed Voyager on my new Laravel project. Even though I did everything on the documentation page on how to install it. I can't go through the admin panel.

I am using Windows 10 right now. And all the routes and pages are inside the vendor folder on my laravel project. How will I access it? How can I access the login page of Voyager.

All the youtube video tutorials uses Macintosh and after the installation of Voyager they can access the login page immediately.

Thank you very much. I pretty much did everything including the upgrading.

Comment: can you explain more what are you getting in output after you serve?

Comment: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 179)

Comment: check your routes by `php artisan route:list` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to try a simple step like with fresh install redirect to projectname/admin/login